# Convert data in a specific format in Apache Pig.

Tags: apache-pig

I want to convert data in to a specific format in Apache Pig so that I can use a reporting tool on top of it.

For example:

```
10:00,abc
10:00,cde
10:01,abc
10:01,abc
10:02,def
10:03,efg
```

The output should be in the following format:

```
        abc   cde  def  efg 
10:00   1      1    0    0
10:01   2      0    0    0
10:02   0      0    1    0
```

The main problem here is that a value can occur multiple times in a row, depending on the different values available in the sample csv file, up to a total of 120.

Any suggestions to tackle this are more than welcome.

Thanks
Gagan

Comment: Looks like you want to denormalize data, maybe this post will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091003/use-pig-to-denormalize-a-large-data-frame

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
A = load 'data' using PigStorage(",") as (key:chararray,value:chararray);

B = foreach A generate key,(value=='abc'?1:0) as abc,(value=='cde'?1:0) as cde,(value=='efg'?1:0) as efg;

C = group B by key;

D = foreach C generate group as key, COUNT(abc) as abc, COUNT(cde) as cde, COUNT(efg) as efg;
```

That should get you a count of the occurances of a particular value for a particular key.

EDIT: just noticed the limit 120 part of the question. If you cannot go above 120 put the following code

```
E = foreach D generate key,(abc>120?"OVER 120":abc) as abc,(cde>120?"OVER 120":cde) as cde,(efg>120?"OVER 120":efg) as efg;
```