# Use Pig to Denormalize A Large Data Frame

Tags: apache-pig

I have a large-ish (21GB) tab-delimited data frame of the form

```
DOCID_1    TERMID_1    TITLE_1    YEAR_1    AUTHOR_1
DOCID_1    TERMID_2    TITLE_1    YEAR_1    AUTHOR_1
...
DOCID_n    TERMID_n    TITLE_n    YEAR_n    AUTHOR_n
```

That is, a (DOCID, TERMID) pair will always uniquely identify a row. What I need, is a data frame in which a DOCID alone uniquely identifies a row, and the TERMIDs are collapsed into a comma-separated chararray list. For example,

```
DOCID_1    TERMID_11, TERMID_12, ..., TERMID_n    TITLE_1    YEAR_1    AUTHOR_1
...
DOCID_n    TERMID_n1, TERMID_n2, ..., TERMID_n    TITLE_1    YEAR_n    AUTHOR_n
```

Can anyone think of a good way of doing this in Pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SEMINORMALIZED = LOAD 'so.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (
    doc_id:chararray
    ,term_id:chararray
    ,title:chararray
    ,year:chararray
    ,author:chararray
);

KEYS = FOREACH SEMINORMALIZED GENERATE 
    doc_id
    ,term_id
;

ATTRIBUTES = FOREACH SEMINORMALIZED GENERATE
    doc_id
    ,title
    ,year
    ,author
;

ATTRIBUTES = DISTINCT ATTRIBUTES;

GROUPED = GROUP KEYS BY doc_id;

ZNF = FOREACH GROUPED GENERATE
    group AS doc_id
    ,KEYS.term_id; AS term_ids

DENORMALIZED = JOIN ZNF BY doc_id, ATTRIBUTES BY doc_id;
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! One thing: to get your example to work, I had to change the last line to "JOIN ZNF BY doc_id". Was that a typo on your part? I'll accept your answer once I figure this out.

Comment: @Kyle. yes it was, thanks for the catch. When you GROUP an alias by a column name, it automatically names whatever you grouped it by to `group`. In the ZNF = statement I renamed it to doc_id.